# PHP to JS (Perhaps to Json) converting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have php array.

```
$array = [
 'John' => 1,
 'Alex' => 15
]
```

I need use data with JS as in example below:

```
[
 ['John', 1],
 ['Alex', 15],
]
```

How can I do that? I tried use json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE flag, but not working for me.

I got this:

```
[{"John":1},{"Alex":15}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Are you getting an error? Is anything being returned at all?

Comment: You currently have an associative PHP array, so that will automatically become an object in JSON. You need to transform this to to an array with simple numeric keys in PHP first, and what is currently the keys needs to become the first value in new sub-arrays.

Comment: nope, I got this: [{"John":1},{"Alex":15}] . What is a better way to replace brackets and quotes?

Comment: Named array keys automatically become objects in JSON instead of arrays. If you want it as an array, you'll have to rebuild it after creating the object.

Answer (score 1):

Is the wrong structure for that output, you would need to loop over and make a new array which has key first and value second.

```
<?php
$array = [
 'John' => 1,
 'Alex' => 15
];

$r = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) $r[] = [$key, $value];

echo json_encode($r, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Then the output would be:

```
[
    [
        "John",
        1
    ],
    [
        "Alex",
        15
    ]
]
```

btw `'` is not valid JSON

Comment: Thank you a lot, now it's working fine.